# How to copy elements from temporary ArrayList into private ArrayList in newly created object?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I am writing a JavaFX program for my school project.
So I have 2 classes, `Product` and controller class.

Inside the `Product` class I have an `ArrayList` that stores parts in each `Product` object created by this class. This `ArrayList` is `private` and can be only accessed by methods `addAssociatedPart`, `deleteAssociatedParts` and `getAllAssociatedParts`.

Inside the controller class I have temporary `ArrayList` that stores said parts until user hits Save button.

Upon hitting save button I would like to copy contents of temporary list into objects private `ArrayList`.

I tried to search online, but figured out I cannot use `Collections.copy` and `clone` methods.

Also upon hitting Save button, Controller class creates `Product` object from textfields filled by user.

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: please provide a code example of your attempts

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities (`List.addAll`, for loop adding items one by one, ...). `Collections.copy` seems one of them so there's probably something else that goes wrong. Please add a [mcve] that allows us to check, where you erred. Also make sure to describe the required sequence of interactions (unless you can assure us of the sequence of executions of teh code snippets by other means). Also make sure how you notice something went wrong (e.g. GUI element x doesn't show desired output, `println` writes unexpected result to the console, debugger shows unexpected results, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addAll` inside `ArrayList` to add all your members to your private list;

```
public void addAssociatedPart(List<Product> productsToAdd) {
   this.privateProducts.addAll(productsToAdd);
}
```

> **public boolean addAll(Collection c)**
>
> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in
>   the order that they are returned by the specified collection's
>   Iterator. The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified
>   collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This
>   implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified
>   collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked. I was actually trying to copy object to a list instead of passing list of an object and copying from there. But your explanation clearly made me see the way it works!